# PHP Image Upload Security - gd / imagick / move_upload_file

Tags: php, imagick

**My present coding for uploading images**
If my coding is hackable, Let me know how will you do it. I will try it myself in my server.

```
if ((strtolower($_FILES["user_image"]["type"]) == "image/jpeg" || strtolower($_FILES["user_image"]["type"]) == "image/pjpeg" || strtolower($_FILES["user_image"]["type"]) == "image/gif" || strtolower($_FILES["user_image"]["type"]) == "image/x-png" || strtolower($_FILES["user_image"]["type"]) == "image/png") && ($_FILES["user_image"]["size"] < 4194304)) {         
            if(strtolower($_FILES["user_image"]["type"]) == "image/jpeg" || strtolower($_FILES["user_image"]["type"]) == "image/pjpeg"){    
                $image_source = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["user_image"]["tmp_name"]);
            }       
            // if uploaded image was GIF
            if(strtolower($_FILES["user_image"]["type"]) == "image/gif"){   
                $image_source = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES["user_image"]["tmp_name"]);
            }           
            // if uploaded image was PNG
            if(strtolower($_FILES["user_image"]["type"]) == "image/x-png" || strtolower($_FILES["user_image"]["type"]) == "image/png"){
                $image_source = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES["user_image"]["tmp_name"]);
            }
```

This is the upload method which i am using.

We can use move_uploaded_file and imagick to upload the files.

Question :

** How will you hack my image uploading code?
( I tried with fake jpeg header and php-gd cleans the file. )
** Why do you tell **move_uploaded_file** is secured than imagecreatefrom[type] (If you say my method is not secured)

I just moved to nginx.
How do i disable all the script execution in uploading directory? php, sh, cgi, ...

```
location /uploads/ { 
  location ~ .*\.(php)?$
  { 
    deny all; 
  }
}
```

** I have never tried **imagick** to upload files to server. I am using it to process the images.

Or do i need to combine those to upload a file a secured way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Nginx, To disable the execution of scripts, your way is correct. To disallow more script types,

```
location ~* ^/(upload|images|more_dirs)/.*\.(php|php5|sh|more_types)$ 
{ 
    deny all; 
}
```